# Why my seven segment is always displaying 9

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

**Hello.I am trying to program stm32f401cb microprocessor to display numbers in the seven segment due to the button actions.Without pressing the button,the program starts with writing 0 in 7segment,after that in every time of pressing to the button,it will display 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and after 9,program will stop.I have written a code like this**

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
void rcc_config(void) {
    RCC_ClocksTypeDef rcc_clocks_init;
    rcc_clocks_init.SYSCLK_Frequency=8400000;
    RCC_GetClocksFreq(&rcc_clocks_init);


}

void gpioa_config(void) {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA,ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpioa_init;
    gpioa_init.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_0;
    gpioa_init.GPIO_Mode= GPIO_Mode_IN;
    gpioa_init.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_PP;
    gpioa_init.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;
    gpioa_init.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA,&gpioa_init);
}
void gpiob_config(void) {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB,ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitTypeDef gpiob_init;
    gpiob_init.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_3 | GPIO_Pin_4 | GPIO_Pin_5 | GPIO_Pin_6;
    gpiob_init.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    gpiob_init.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_PP;
    gpiob_init.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    gpiob_init.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB,&gpiob_init);



}
void number_0(void) {
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_0); //a
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_1); //b
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_2); //c
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_3); //d
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_4);  //e
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_5); //f
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_6); //g

}
```

The problem is normally the program starts with displaying zero(0) but when i press the button for the first time,it displays 9 and after that,it always displays 9(nine) in the 7segment everytime i press the button

counter control function is used to display according to the counter,normally it should display 0 when j=0,1 when j=1,2 when j=2 etc... but it always displays 9 after the first time i press the button.

What may be the reason of that you think??

[image: didnt press the button]

[image: pressed multiple times]

Comment: Do you wait for the button to be released before checking it again? If not, maybe it just counts up from 0 to 9 faster than the eye can see. You should really show us the code that is checking the button and incrementing the counter.

Comment: Are you debouncing the switch?  It doesn't look like it from either the hardware or software side.

Comment: How to debounce the switch? i dont know,can you inform me please?

Comment: From a quick Google search, I found [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/563160/help-with-a-simple-debounce-program-on-stm32) for software debounce and [this image](https://imgur.com/gallery/IpdV6UB) for hardware.  This is a super common issue and there are many other resources out there to help with it.

Comment: Read [a guide to denouncing](http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing.htm) by Jack Ganssle, and also lower your `gpioa_init.GPIO_Speed` to lower speed, the higher the the speed the noisier it going to get, a button is certain don’t need 100MHz